Is it valid to define sets using the ¬ operator?
I was wondering if you could define a set this way:
$A=\{\forall x \in \mathbb{R}/x>3\}\\ B=\{\forall x \in \mathbb{R}/ \neg x>3\}$
Or also:
$B=\{\forall x \in \mathbb{R}/ \neg x \in A\}$
Are any of these declarations valid?

Those $\forall$ symbols are incorrect and not needed. Using $/$ rather than $:$ or $\mid$ to separate the declarations of the variable from the conditions on it in set builder notation  is unusual. The use of negation in the conditions is fine.

I could see how for all could be redundant, but incorrect? This is standard notation in my country so I this comes as a surprise to me, thanks for taking the time to answer the question.

Which country uses $/$ to mean such that in its set builder notation?

I am from Italy, and this is on my math textbook, not to mention every teacher I've had used this notation as well, I was also aware of the : but it's not as used here.

Don't put $\forall$ and $\exists$ inside a set definition.

You can define sets using $\neg$, just like you can use any logical symbol, but you should make sure that it is applying to statements and not elements or sets.
So it might be better to write $B=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\neg(x\in A)\}$ to make it clear you are negating the statement $x\in A$ and not mistakenly trying to take the negation of $x$.
As an aside, for the 'such that' symbol used in defining sets, it is better to use a colon : or a vertical line | instead of a slash.

+1 but you haven't mentioned the spurious $\forall$ symbols.

Thank you, I am sorry for improper use of some symbols, I think it might be due to a different notation preferences and conventions in my country; on an unrelated note, what does it even mean to negate an element?

@absolutelygab: it doesn't anything to negate an element (unless you are working in a context where the symbol $\lnot$ is being used for more than one purpose, e.g., if you were working with Boolean algebras). Hence the brackets that Francis recommends are for clarity, but aren't strictly necessary in most contexts.

In terms of Boolean algebra negation is a fundamental operation, so that obviously makes sense, I was curious about its algebraic application (which doesn't exist), thanks for clarifying.
